# HTML5 audio play in android but its current time return always zero

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have write a code for playing audio and getting its current time. and according to current time i perform different action. Its working fine in Desktop but in android tab and mobile current time returns always zero while audio play.

But when I play a HTML5 video tag its return current time correct. Please advice anyone how to resolve it?

The code is given Below :-

```
    <video id="a3" width="320" height="176" controls>
      <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
      Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video>

    <audio preload='auto' controls id='a2'>
      <source src="http://arbordalepublishing.com/eBooks2/Animalogy/Animalogy p7.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
<div id="clickTime"></div>

<div id="currentTime"></div>
    <br>
    <span id="W10">Chick </span>
    <span id="W11">is </span>
    <span id="W12">to </span>
    <span id="W13">feathery,</span>
    <span id="W14">as </span>
    <span id="W15">bear </span>
    <span id="W16">is </span>
    <span id="W17">to </span>
    <span id="W18">furry.</span>


    <button onclick="getCurTime()" type="button">Get current time position</button>
    <button onclick="setCurTime()" type="button">Set time position to 5 seconds</button><br>
```

Java Script Code :

```
<script>

// NOTE: these are not 100% synchronized - they are just for example
var words = [
    {id: "W10", start: 0, end: 0.7, highlighted: false},
    {id: "W11", start: 0.76, end: 1.1, highlighted: false},
    {id: "W12", start: 1.2, end: 1.3, highlighted: false},
    {id: "W13", start: 1.4, end: 2.1, highlighted: false},
    {id: "W14", start: 2.1, end: 2.3, highlighted: false},
    {id: "W15", start: 2.3, end: 2.7, highlighted: false},
    {id: "W16", start: 2.7, end: 3.0, highlighted: false},
    {id: "W17", start: 3.0, end: 3.2, highlighted: false},
    {id: "W18", start: 3.2, end: 3.4, highlighted: false}],
  audio = document.getElementById("a2");

audio.onplaying = highlight;

function highlight() {
  var time = audio.currentTime, i = 0, word;
    var ct = document.getElementById('currentTime');
    ct.innerHTML += time+" ";
    for(; word = words[i++];) {
        if (time >= word.start && time < word.end) {
          if (!word.highlighted) {
            word.highlighted = true; // to reduce the need to update DOM
            document.getElementById(word.id).style.color = "orange";
          }
        }
        else if (word.highlighted) {
            document.getElementById(word.id).style.color = "black";
            word.highlighted = false;
        }
    }

  // you should listen to end event and stop the loop using that, here, for simplicity:
  if (!audio.paused) setTimeout(highlight, 17);
  //else alert("done");
}


function getCurTime() { 

    document.getElementById("clickTime").innerHTML=audio.currentTime;
} 

function setCurTime() { 
    audio.currentTime=5;
} 


</script>
```